# Speed up for each row loop [Uipath, invoke VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, uipath

I have a requirement to apply auto fit for the merged cells, it’s working fine.

I am using Uipath for each data table from input and I am applying VBA the below.

When I run this it takes more time because I’ve (oRange) value totally 40000 rows.

Each row takes more time, can this convert into Vb.net or any other way to run it fast?? Please advise.

```vb
Public Sub AutoFitMergedCells(oRange)
      Dim tHeight As Integer
      Dim iPtr As Integer
      Dim oldWidth As Single
      Dim oldZZWidth As Single
      Dim newWidth As Single
      Dim newHeight As Single
    Set oRange = Range(""+oRange+"")
     
      With Sheets("MASTER")
        oldWidth = 0
        For iPtr = 1 To oRange.Columns.Count
          oldWidth = oldWidth + .Cells(1, oRange.Column + iPtr - 1).ColumnWidth
        Next iPtr
       'oldWidth = .Cells(1, oRange.Column).ColumnWidth + .Cells(1, oRange.Column + 1).ColumnWidth
        oRange.MergeCells = False
        newWidth = Len(.Cells(oRange.Row, oRange.Column).Value)
        oldZZWidth = .Range("ZZ1").ColumnWidth
        .Range("ZZ1") = Left(.Cells(oRange.Row, oRange.Column).Value, newWidth)
        .Range("ZZ1").WrapText = True
        .Columns("ZZ").ColumnWidth = oldWidth
        .Rows("1").EntireRow.AutoFit
        newHeight = .Rows("1").RowHeight / oRange.Rows.Count
        .Rows(CStr(oRange.Row) & ":" & CStr(oRange.Row + oRange.Rows.Count - 1)).RowHeight = newHeight
        oRange.MergeCells = True
        oRange.WrapText = True
        .Range("ZZ1").ClearContents
        .Range("ZZ1").ColumnWidth = oldZZWidth
      End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use singles (they are from the past). Processors are optimised to use doubles.

Comment: if I changed double instead of singles will it speed up?

Comment: I'm not expressing any other opinion about your code (except I did check you were using `with` which is faster and you were). So in the past CPUs only did `Single`.  Now they do `Doubles`. All CPUs are optimised for current data types.

Comment: I doubt there's much you can do to optimize that except maybe turn off `ScreenUpdating` and set Calculation to manual

Comment: Hi Tim , can you please explain in detail where i should turn off ??